# How to convert this nested dictionary into one single dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
a = {"a": "b", "c": "d", {"e": "E", "f": "F"}}
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
b = {"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "E", "f": "F"}
```

Comment: That's not a valid literal - did you mean `{"a": "b", "c": "d", "something": {"e": "E"}}`? Also, what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

First your dict is not valid, it should be always a key value pair. Below it is what should be case for your dict

```
a = {"a": "b", "c": "d", 'something':{"e": "E", "f": "F"}}

def func(dic):
    re ={}
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            re.update(v)
        else:
            re.update({k:v})
    return re

print(func(a))
```

output

```
 {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'E', 'f': 'F'}
```

Comment: I got this problem from a technical job interview (on skype) and was unable to solve this problem. She told me to convert into one dictionary. You are right , this is not a valid dict. Thanks dear for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with losing the key to which your inner dict belongs to (you did not specify what to do with it),
I would do it recursively:

```py
def unnest_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result.update(unnest_dict(v))
        else:
            result[k] = v
    return result
unnest_dict({"a": "b", "c": "d", "something":{"e": "E", "f": "F"}})
```

{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'E', 'f': 'F'}

Comment: I got this problem from a technical job interview (on skype) and was unable to solve this problem. She told me to convert into one dictionary. You are right , this is not a valid dict. Thanks dear for help.